# I need an advice in building a website builder similar to bubble.io

Tags: docker, performance, security, kubernetes

We are currently building a website builder similar to bubble.io, we will not be able to add all the features our users will need, so we  want them to be able to extend the functions of their apps with JavaScript, we want to isolate each users website on a k8s container to prevent malicious JavaScript code from spreading.
My question is are there better alternatives than using containers?

Comment: Hi there and welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately the format of this site is not well suited to this kind of open-ended question. There is no single best answer. You'll just have to try many options and see what works best for you and your team.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to isolation, physical machines are always the best. Followed by VMs and then containers.

However, it is not practical to have physical machines for each and every user. If you truly want to use Kubernetes then having separate VMs isn't practical either.
So it leaves you with containers.

However, containers are running on the host machine and *can* be escaped from if not secured properly. Luckily, technology is advanced enough to be able to use the scaling advantages of containers and add additional security features to prevent those escapes. Container security is a big topic, too big explain everything in detail in one answer, so I won't be able to explain everything to you, however, I'll point out some things that may be interesting.

From what you described, here are some ideas what to look into:

- Properly split your (customers) applications in separate namespaces and use [NetworkPolicies](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/) to ensure these namespaces cannot interact with each other
- Make use of [PodSecurityPolicies](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/pod-security-policy/) to ensure that the creation of containers with unnecessary privileges is not possible
- Secure the environment of your containers by using [gVisor](https://github.com/google/gvisor) or [kata containers](https://github.com/kata-containers/kata-containers)
- Use scanners to check code and images for possible vulnerabilities whenever your customer submits them (e.g. [sonarqube](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube), [trivy](https://github.com/aquasecurity/trivy), ...)

With all that being said, as you can see it is not an easy task to have that kind of a safe environment.
So if possible, don't let people submit their own code that runs on your infrastructure. It is not impossible, but it takes a lot of time, cost and effort to secure these kind of environments properly. There are many things I skipped, simply because there is no end when it comes to security, so please be aware that there is **never** absolute security, not even when using physical machines.

Comment: PSPs are deprecated and pending removal, do not start using them now :)

Comment: They are going to be removed in Kubernetes 1.25, which means that there still is over a year until that happens, so it can still be used for the time being since it is easier to simply have a YAML describing security settings than switching to something like OPA for example and learning Rego.

Answer (score 0):

Overall building this kind of product is not recommended. There is no security system available that is good enough to run arbitrary user code without extensive in-house expertise and full-time support staff. Don't enter this area lightly.